# How to iterate over tuple of trait objects or unsized types

Tags: rust, iterator, trait-objects, mutable-reference

This question was originally found in [this post in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/8cfqvb/is_there_a_way_to_iterate_over_a_tuple/).

Whilst experienced Rust user will spot out that the elements in a tuple does not have to be the same (if they are, you should use array!), and so it does not make sense to iterate through them, there are still some cases this is useful.

Those cases are that the types of the tuple can be casted to the same unsized type (for example `[u8]` or `dyn Trait`).

Demostration:

```
trait Dummy {}
impl Dummy for () {}
impl Dummy for i32 {}

fn mut_tuple_to_iter(v: &mut ((), i32)) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut dyn D> {
    //How do I implement this?
}
```

I couldn't find a beautiful way to write the above. Any idea?

---

To see a possible answer that is not beautiful enough, here it is:

```
use core::iter::once;

trait D {}
impl D for () {}
impl D for i32 {}

fn mut_tuple_to_iter(v: &mut ((), i32)) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut dyn D> {
    once(&mut v.0 as &mut dyn D).chain(once(&mut v.1 as &mut dyn D))
}
```

[Play ground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3478eb45b08e47e98f6cdccb7fba64a7)

Comment: The only difficulty with this comes from the requirement that you want _mutable_ references to the tuple items, which I believe is only possible with unsafe code. For shared references this is easy to implement.

Comment: No that's not true. I will update the post and you will see.

Comment: OK, you've proven me wrong. In this particular case, you can indeed create all necessary mutable references right in the function itself, so the compiler can verify that each tuple element is mutably referenced only once. Collections of variable length often require unsafe code for mutable iterators, since the compiler can't prove that each reference is only returned once.

Comment: After you have included an answer in the question, I'm not sure what the question is now.

Comment: Yes... I found an answer, but I HAAATE it because it is ugly. I am looking for a better way to do the same thing. If there is no better answers come through I may end up write a macro to hide the ugly stuff.

Comment: I'd honestly use a macro for this specific case.

Comment: The reason it's ugly is because you're not supposed to do it.

Comment: @trentcl Why I shouldn't do it? The code is legal and does the correct thing. It does not violate any rules.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out that I don't have to specify the type:

```
fn mut_tuple_to_iter(v:&mut ((), i32)) ->impl Iterator<Item=&mut dyn D> {
    once(&mut v.0 as _).chain(once(&mut v.1 as _))
}
```

will work. This makes it much less ugly already!

Of cause, a macro will help a lot:

```
macro_rules! chained_elements {
    ($exp: expr) => {
        core::iter::once($exp as _)
    };
    ($exp: expr, $($rest:tt)*) => {
        core::iter::once($exp as _)
        .chain(chained_elements!($($rest)*))
    }
}
```

Now you can write

```rust
use core::iter::once;

trait D {}
impl D for () {}
impl D for i32 {}

macro_rules! chained_elements {
    ($exp: expr) => {
        core::iter::once($exp as _)
    };
    ($exp: expr, $($rest:tt)*) => {
        core::iter::once($exp as _)
        .chain(chained_elements!($($rest)*))
    }
}

fn mut_tuple_to_iter(v: &mut ((), i32)) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut dyn D> {
    chained_elements!(&mut v.0, &mut v.1)
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0948f3118fe8f6a33c67f8b586351703)

## Discussions

I have been exploring the design space in rust for a long time, but in some cases the above is the only solution.

The reason of it is that when you have to use trait objects (for example, to reduce generic explosion), as call-by-value is not an option (yet), call-by-mutable-reference is the best thing you can have. In such cases, a pattern like the above seems inevitable.